# Hibernate exceptionCould not parse configuration: .\WEB-INF\hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: hibernate, jboss

I am getting the following exception when running my application in JBoss.

**

- Exceptions

**

> 2010-02-17 15:10:43,435 INFO  [STDOUT]
>   (main) ERROR [2010-10-17 03:10] [main]
>   (HibernateUtil.java:22) - Hibernate
>   exceptionCould not parse
>   configuration:
>   .\WEB-INF\hibernate.cfg.xml 2010-02-17
>   15:10:43,435 ERROR
>   [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/Wimax]]
>   (main) StandardWrapper.Throwable
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could
>   not initialize class
>   x.x.x.x.HibernateUtil

and also

> 2010-02-17 15:10:43,373 INFO  [STDOUT]
>   (main) Warning: Caught exception
>   attempting to use SAX to load a SAX
>   XMLReader  2010-02-17 15:10:43,373
>   INFO  [STDOUT] (main) Warning:
>   Exception was:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser
>   cannot be cast to
>   org.xml.sax.XMLReader 2010-02-17
>   15:10:43,373 INFO  [STDOUT] (main)
>   Warning: I will print the stack trace
>   then carry on using the default SAX
>   parser 2010-02-17 15:10:43,373 ERROR
>   [STDERR] (main)
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser
>   cannot be cast to
>   org.xml.sax.XMLReader

My application is using Hibernate 3.0. I am running the application in eclipse and deploying in JBoss-5.1 with jdk version. The same application works fine in Apache Tomcat.

Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

could you try removing the hibernate JAR's from the EAR/WAR file when deploying on JBoss. doesn't jboss come with it's own version of hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

you should add Hibernate jar file to eclipse class path.

if you have JavaEE project, than project>properties>JavaEE - add All button. To add all dependecies as runtime JavaEE dependencies.

and! =) you should check if you have added same jars (with different versions) in you classpath.

Comment: I have already added the jars. Even after that it is giving the exceptions.

Comment: Check for same jars with different versions. Maybe there are two "same" classes in one classloader. Notice that they are not equal.

Check jar dependencies versions.
Hope it helps.